# Populating Listbox using Jquery and passing values with Model on submit

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

1. Nothing is being added to my Listbox
2. Once i DO get these items added to the listbox, how do I pass it through with my model on submit ?

The values from the Controller ARE being pulled through, as I tested using an alert. What am I missing that is not passing through these values to my listbox?

View:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    @Html.Label("Items", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedAccountItems, Model.UserItems, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlistaccountitems", @multiple = "multiple" })*@
    @Html.ListBox("ItemsDDL", new SelectList(new[] { "" }),new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlistaccountitems", @multiple = "multiple" })
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#ddlistcategory").change(function () {
        var catItem = $("#ddlistcategory").val();

        $("#ddlistaccountitems").empty();
        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories", "Account")',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "Post",
                data: { "i": catItem },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        //alert(key + " " + val);
                        $("#ddlistaccountitems").append('<option id="5">5</option>');
                    })
                }
            });
        });
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetCategories(string i)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> lstCategories = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            lstCategories.Add("1", "Beverages");
            lstCategories.Add("2", "Condiments");
            lstCategories.Add("3", "Confections");
            lstCategories.Add("4", "Dairy Products");
            lstCategories.Add("5", "Grains/Cereals");
            lstCategories.Add("6", "Meat/Poultry");
            lstCategories.Add("7", "Produce");
            lstCategories.Add("8", "Seafood");
            return Json(lstCategories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

So - Typical - after posting for help after HOURS of struggling, I get the solution!

My problem was that my ListBox was ACTUALLY called ItemsDDL, so the @id = "ddlistaccountitems" was not recognized.

So I figured out how to pass the values to my model as well:

VIEW:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     @Html.Label("Items", new { @class = "control-label" })
     @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedAccountItems, Model.UserItems, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlistaccountitems", @multiple = "multiple" })
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#ddlistcategory").change(function () {
        var catItem = $("#ddlistcategory").val();

        $("#ItemsDDL").empty();
        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories", "Account")',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "Post",
                data: { "i": catItem },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        //alert(key + " " + val);
                        $("#ddlistaccountitems").append('<option id="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>');
                    })
                }
            });
        });
```